# magento 2.4 how to add a price field in system.xml

Tags: price, configuration, system.xml, magento2.4.4, system-config

On my magento 2.4.4 I'm creating a new module with its configuration in system.xml. The file itself works fine, I've created a yes/no field to enable/disable my feature plus an input text to add some data:

```
<field id="enabled" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Enabled</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
<field id="customfield" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Custom Field</label>
</field>
```

My issue is that my "custom field" should have a price inside, so I'd like to have the field not as a simple text but as a proper field price (like the one in the product form). I've looked on the internet but I cannot find what type to use instead of "type to order to have a price input field.

Does such a type even exist? How can I edit my field to have a proper price field?

Thanks

Comment: you can check [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/370180/110348) for add price field on system.xml

Answer (score 1):

In System.xml, when you need to add a restriction on a specific field, you can achieve this by adding embedded validators within your configuration file. There exists a variety of validators, including:

1. validate-select
2. required-entry
3. validate-number
4. validate-digits
5. validate-not-negative-number
   and several others.

In the context of your specific requirement, you should utilize the validate-number validator to enforce numeric value constraints.

Your code should be:

```
<field id="enabled" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Enabled</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
<field id="customfield" translate="label comment" type="text" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Custom Field</label>
    <validate>validate-number</validate>
</field>
```