# magento 2.4 system.xml validate decimal number

Tags: configuration, validation, system.xml, magento2.4.4, decimal-number

I have an input type text field in my system.xml . I'd like this field to be validated in a way that the user can put numbers (0 to 9) and dots but not commas nor any other symbol.

In magento, I have the class "validate-number", that doesn't discriminate against commas versus dots. Same for "validate-digits": with this one, I can only put numbers, not dots.

Is there a way to validate decimal numbers with only dots as decimal separator?

Comment: If I understand your question, this is the same problem as your previous question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/370177/45441

Comment: they're related but they're not the same.. agreed that I could have posted the two question in a single post as one is the alternative of the other: does a proper field  type for price exists? If not, is there a validation we can use to validate prices? The answer to both is no: there is no ready type for price field and no, there is no ready validation to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to add Custom Validation To System Configuration Field

1.add a field on **`system.xml`** file

```
<field id="your_field_id" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Your Field Label</label>
    <validate>validate-number-and-dot</validate>
</field>
```

2.Create requirejs-config file **`requirejs-config.js`** in **`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml`** folder with the following code.

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/validation': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

3.Create js file **`validation.js`** in **`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js`** folder with the following code.

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (target) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-number-and-dot',
            function (value) {
                return /^[0-9.]+$/.test(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('"Please enter numbers (0-9) and dots (.) only."')
        );
        return target;
    };
});
```

Comment: so there's no an already existing validation, I have to create one.. thanks for the steps, they're really helpful